# ESLint problems with Typegoose

Tags: typescript, eslint, lint, typegoose

I'm having some problems linting my code.

Now I'm using the following versions:

- "typescript": "^4.8.2",
- "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.34.0",
- "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.34.0",
- "eslint": "^6.5",

Here's my .eslintrc.yml file

```
---
  # Env Vars #
  env:
    es6: true
    node: true

  ignorePatterns:
    - "!.*"
    - "**/node_modules/.*"

  # Parser vars #
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"
  parserOptions:
    ecmaVersion: 2018

  # Plugins #
  plugins:
    - "@typescript-eslint"
    - mongodb
  extends:
    - plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended
  
  # Rules #
  rules:
    indent:
      - 1
      - tab
      - SwitchCase: 1
    no-undef: 2
    no-unreachable: 2
    no-unused-expressions: 1
    no-unused-vars: 0
    comma-dangle:
      - 1
      - only-multiline
    no-multi-spaces:
      - 1
      - exceptions:
          VariableDeclarator: true
    no-shadow-restricted-names: 0
    eqeqeq:
      - 1
      - smart
    no-dupe-keys: 2
    no-duplicate-case: 2
    no-extra-semi: 2
    max-depth:
      - 1
      - 4
    no-empty: 2
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": off
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": off
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": off
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore": off
    "@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix": off
    "@typescript-eslint/class-name-casing": off
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define":
      - error
      - functions: false
        classes: true
    "@typescript-eslint/no-extra-parens": 2
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": 0
```

But it's returning some linting errors for me when I'm importing Typegoose types, for an example:

`error 'index' is defined but never used`

```
import { index } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

@index({
    user: 1,
    deleted: 1,
    facility: 1,
        provider: 1,
}, {
    background: true,
})
```

and also with the indentation

`warning Expected indentation of 1 tab but found 0`

this expects the index to be like this, which is awful:

```
@index({
    user: 1,
    deleted: 1,
    facility: 1,
    provider: 1,
    }, {
    background: true,
    })
```

If anyone have a clue of what is happening I'd appreciate <3

I already tried all types of rules of ESLint, but I don't want to disable `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` because it's useful on other parts of the code

Comment: [Ask only one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/393723). Let's pretend I have the answer to your first question but not your second. Why would I bother to post an answer if I know you wouldn't mark it as the accepted answer? You artificially constrain the population of people that might try to answer you when you ask multiple questions in one post.

Comment: Explain why you think `error 'index' is defined but never used` is an invalid rule violation. I don't see you using `index` anywhere in your code sample. Explain on what line `warning Expected indentation of 1 tab but found 0` is occurring and why you think it should remove the indentation before `provider`.

Comment: i cannot reproduce the issue in modern version of eslint / typescript-eslint, maybe consider updating to more up-to-date versions? reproduction repository & branch https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose-testing/tree/SO76232623; maybe the old version somehow cannot deal with decorators; for context there is currently eslint 8.x out and typescript-eslint 5.x